# PostgreSQL - Avoid listing the same IN() values twice

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query on a customer referrals table in which each row contains the customer id of a referring customer, and a referred customer. So if Bob with custID 100 refers John with custID 200 to our product, we enter a row in the referrals table where referring_user_id is 100 and referred_user_id is 200.

Given a list of user_ids, I want to search both the referring_user_id column and the referred_user_id column for any matches. The only way I figured out how to do this is to do an OR on both columns, and copy the list of user_ids twice like so:

```
SELECT
    ---columns---
FROM tbl_referrals REF
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile PRF1 ON REF.referring_user_id = PRF1.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile PRF2 ON REF.referred_user_id = PRF2.user_id
WHERE
    PRF1.user_id IN (
        'id100',
        'id200',
        'id300',
        'id400'
    )
    OR PRF2.user_id IN (
        'id100',
        'id200',
        'id300',
        'id400'
    )
ORDER BY REF.referred_user_id
limit 100;
```

Is there a way to write this query without writing the whole list of ids twice? This is post-gres btw, but I think it applies to all SQL.

Comment: Note:the **LEFT** JOINs make no sense here.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `LEFT` join is becoming an `INNER` join because you are filtering the right tables in your where clause.

Because both of your join predicates are referencing the same filtered column, `user_id`, you could simplify your query to this:

```
SELECT
---columns---
FROM tbl_referrals REF
JOIN tbl_profile PRF1 ON REF.referring_user_id = PRF1.user_id
                      OR REF.referred_user_id = PRF1.user_id
WHERE PRF1.user_id IN ('id100','id200','id300','id400')
ORDER BY REF.referred_user_id
LIMIT 100;
```

**Edit for comment:**

You could use conditional aggregation to get both names for the select:

```
SELECT 
     MAX(CASE WHEN REF.referring_user_id = PRF1.user_id THEN PRF1.Name END) ReferringName,
     MAX(CASE WHEN REF.referred_user_id = PRF1.user_id THEN PRF1.Name END) ReferredName,
     ---other columns---
FROM tbl_referrals REF
JOIN tbl_profile PRF1 ON REF.referring_user_id = PRF1.user_id
                      OR REF.referred_user_id = PRF1.user_id
WHERE PRF1.user_id IN ('id100','id200','id300','id400')
GROUP BY ---other columns---
ORDER BY REF.referred_user_id
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: This looks nice, but I need to join on tbl_profile twice because I need to select the names of the rererring_user and the referred_user. So I need something like `SELECT PRF1.name, PRF2.name` in the select statement.

Comment: @user3685285 You could likely use conditional aggregation for that, I added an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a mini table with the desired IDs and inner join it to the existing tables.  This way you only specify the IDs once.  It would look like:

```
SELECT
---columns---
FROM tbl_referrals REF
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile PRF1 ON REF.referring_user_id = PRF1.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_profile PRF2 ON REF.referred_user_id = PRF2.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 'id100' AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT 'id200' AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT 'id300' AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT 'id400' AS id
) IDS
on IDS.id = PRF1.user_id OR IDS.id = PRF2.user_id
ORDER BY REF.referred_user_id
limit 100;
```

Comment: The `select .. union` can be simplified to `( values  ('id100'), ('id200') ... )`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you make this another answer with your version?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ids(id) AS (VALUES('{id100,id200,id300,id400}'::text[]))
SELECT
    ---columns---
FROM tbl_referrals REF
  JOIN ids ON (REF.referring_user_id = ANY(ids.id) OR REF.referred_user_id = ANY(ids.id))
  LEFT JOIN tbl_profile PRF1 ON REF.referring_user_id = PRF1.user_id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_profile PRF2 ON REF.referred_user_id = PRF2.user_id
ORDER BY REF.referred_user_id
limit 100;
```